# Issues with downloading anaconda, and running tensorflow 1.10 on spyder

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have had issues with anaconda and spyder and tensorflow on windows. I get that in spyder tensorflow is not imported and I have added it to my python path.. any help on the full process would be great help

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your command line and write:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Installation process should start.

Same when other packages you need are not available.

Comment: Anaconda has now made it possible to install even the gpu version of tensorflow using a single line command without requiring the dependency of installing NVIDIA driver on you own. It would be good if you can update your answer in case thats useful to others!
Source: [Tensorflow in Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/)

Comment: thanks i had issues with syncing tensorflow with spyder, and used pip install tensorflow.